# How to properly use variables and Math.round

Tags: javascript, html

So i have this javascript that updates a paragraph, but it only outputs `NaN`. When i check the `var coins` it outputs `?` before i click the button, i and if i push the button in the HTML it adds `0.01` every time i click it, and then my output ends up like this `?0.010.010.010.01.01...` Any idea why this happens?

```js
var Cpc = 0.01; //Coins per Click
var coins = 0; //Coins
var cps = 0; //Coins per Sec

setInterval(update, 10);

function update() {
    var coinsFix = Number(Math.round(coins + 'e2') + 'e-2');
    document.getElementById('Coins').innerHTML = coinsFix + ' $';
    document.getElementById('CoinsB').innerHTML = coinsFix;
    document.getElementById('Cps').innerHTML = cps + ' Cps';
}

function CPC() {
    function cpc() {
        var addCoins = coins + Cpc;
        return addCoins;
    }
    coins = cpc();
}
```

```html
<div class="rightBox"> 
  <div id="ClickSpot">
    <button id="clickButton" onClick="CPC()"> <img src="ClickerCoin.png" alt="ClickerSpot" class="ClickerSpot"> </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottomBox">
  <p id="Coins">Coins</p>
  <div id="CoinsB" style="display: none"></div>
  <p id="Cps">Cps</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what should round doing?

Comment: It's because when i add 0.01 to coins it gets alot of decimals, and i only want to show two decimals

Comment: Ah... Then use `toFixed();`. It lets you set the decimal precision, but returns a string.

Comment: @t.niese, i have just updated it. It happens in Chrome

Comment: That's interesting, it does not happen here.

Comment: Yes, and i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: But if you check `coins` which is not change anywhere and coins reports `?` and not `0`, then there might be another problem. How do you check the content of `coins`?

Comment: When i load my page i open the browser console and types in `console.log(coins)` and i have tryed just typing in `coins` and that is the same result. No it works as it should when i run the snippet.

Comment: And what about the code snippet here on SO? If you click on `run code snippet` in your question,  does this show the same behavior to you?

Comment: Yes it works as expected here on OS

Comment: BOL, javascript has always been bad at maths xD

Comment: If it works as expected on SO then there might be something else in your code that overwrites the `coins`.

Comment: @t.niese that is the only code so far

Comment: If the given code works for you on SO the the problem is clearly somewhere else. So something else in your setup is responsible for this problem.

Comment: I guess that I will have to rewrite it line by line till I find it

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Number.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) with two digits. The result is a string.

> The **`toFixed()`** method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

```
var coinsFix = coins.toFixed(2);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var Cpc = 0.01; //Coins per Click
var coins = 0; //Coins
var cps = 0; //Coins per Sec

setInterval(update, 10);

function update() {
    var coinsFix = coins.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('Coins').innerHTML = coinsFix + ' $';
    document.getElementById('CoinsB').innerHTML = coinsFix;
    document.getElementById('Cps').innerHTML = cps + ' Cps';
}

function CPC() {
    function cpc() {
        var addCoins = coins + Cpc;
        return addCoins;
    }
    coins = cpc();
}
```

```html
<div class="rightBox"> 
  <div id="ClickSpot">
    <button id="clickButton" onClick="CPC()"> <img src="ClickerCoin.png" alt="ClickerSpot" class="ClickerSpot"> </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottomBox">
  <p id="Coins">Coins</p>
  <div id="CoinsB" style="display: none"></div>
  <p id="Cps">Cps</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
setInterval(update, 10);
```

to

```
setInterval("update()", 10);
```

also

```
var coinsFix = Number(Math.round(coins + 'e2') + 'e-2');
```

to

```
var coinsFix = coins.toFixed(2);
```

Try this:

```
var Cpc = 0.01; //Coins per Click
var coins = 0; //Coins
var cps = 0; //Coins per Sec

setInterval("update()", 10);

function update() {
    var coinsFix = coins.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('Coins').innerHTML = coinsFix + ' $';
    document.getElementById('CoinsB').innerHTML = coinsFix;
    document.getElementById('Cps').innerHTML = cps + ' Cps';
}

function CPC() {
    function cpc() {
        var addCoins = coins + Cpc;
        return addCoins;
    }
    coins = cpc();
}


<div class="rightBox"> 
  <div id="ClickSpot">
    <button id="clickButton" onClick="CPC()"> <img src="ClickerCoin.png" alt="ClickerSpot" class="ClickerSpot"> </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottomBox">
  <p id="Coins">Coins</p>
  <div id="CoinsB" style="display: none"></div>
  <p id="Cps">Cps</p>enter code here
</div>
```